# Maven - Excluding Transitive Dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build

I am trying to exclude transitive dependency using following in the pom file

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>xxxxx</groupId>
      <artifactId>xxxxxx</artifactId>
       <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>yyyyyyy</groupId>
            <artifactId>yyyyyyy</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

where xxxxxx is the project I need. I am trying to avoid the transitive dependent project yyyyyy, that comes with it as it conflicts with the other version of the same project I already have as dependency.

When i build my project with this configuration and refresh eclipse, the project yyyyyyy-version.jar still shows in my classpath entry. I have to manually delete that classpath entry to make it work.

Please guide what am i doing wrong here. How to specify the exclusion in pom file so that I don't get this classpath entry.Thanks.

Update - I am not having any problem in the build but while i try to run the application , it find a particular parameter in 2 versions of a project - The desired one and the undesired one coming as a transitive dependency.

Comment: Is it explicitly the only thing that depends on it (the undesired library/version)?

Comment: Thanks Dave for your help. I don't see this undesired library / version when I see dependency tree. Not sure how its getting to classpath.

Comment: This is the error I am getting - Parameter ' in file (fileType DECLARATION) jar:file: (undesired project /version ) was previously declared in jar:file: ( Desired project / version ) (fileType DECLARATION).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform `mvn dependency:tree` and analyze who has this transitive dependency too. Currently, there is no global exclude feature but an appropriate [JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-1977) exists.

Comment: After the above exclusion in the pom file, I tried running mvn dependency: tree on the paremt project and surprisingly i don't see this ( undesired project version ) in the dependency tree. Not sure how its coming in my classpath entry.

Comment: This is the error I am getting - Parameter ' in file (fileType DECLARATION) jar:file: (undesired project /version ) was previously declared in jar:file: ( Desired project / version ) (fileType DECLARATION).

Comment: @Michael-O Can you explain what you mean by: ´Currently, there is not global exclude feature but the appropriate JIRA issue is available`?

Comment: @khmarbaise I have linked the JIRA issue. In my answer. The wording wasn't proper.